# Javascript button with jQuery blockUI not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a event where the `button` after clicked, it pop up a image saying "please, wait.." for some seconds. Before that it check if the image was uploaded.. if not upload it say you need to upload a image... if it got uploaded, I would like to see the "please wait" for some seconds using `blockIU.js`

When I click in the button, it doesn't check if the image got uploaded and go to the next page.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
      $("#ir").click(function() {
        var fileName = $('#imagem').val();
        if (fileName == '') {
          alert("Por favor, Envie uma foto");
          return false; // to prevent form submit
        } else {
          $.blockUI();
          setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
        }
      });
    });                                                                     
</script>
```

I already added the scripts and the CSS in the html
check below:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
```

here is the css:

```
<style>
   div.blockMsg {
      width:  40%;
      top:    30%;
      left:   30%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #f00;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; 
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50); 
      -moz-opacity:.70;
      opacity:.70;
      padding: 15px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    #main { padding: 30px }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
  
  $("#ir").click(function() {
    $.blockUI();
    var fileName = $('#imagem').val();
    if (fileName == '') {
      $.unblockUI();
      alert("Por favor, Envie uma foto");
      return false; // to prevent form submit
    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $.unblockUI();
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: SHiladitya, for some unknow reason.. it is not working... why ?? do you want to see my entire html file ?

Comment: for some reason, the 2000 second it not working. I increased to 10000 to see it hold, but it doesnt

Comment: @ALessandro: we try to discourage requests for private chat details, as that places an unnecessarily high burden on a person to help you further, on a volunteer basis. Please try to obtain all your help here in public, so others can benefit from the conversation and public answers. If you want to share additional code, edit it into your question.

Comment: SUre, no problems I understand completly !!